# Inserir varios Itens com o mesmo IDPEDIDO Sql sever

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, sql-insert

Olá 
Como posso inserir varios itens para um unico ID Primarykey autoincrement
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

do ainda haverá colunas dos IDprodutos onde quero inserir vários itens para um ID_Pedido como faço isso já tentei com update mais ele vai ficar sobrescrevendo o registro anterior.
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Você quer criar uma outra tabela pra inserir os itens? Isso?

Comment: Olá então a tabela queria saber se consigo usar essa ou necessito usar uma outra para conseguir adicionar os itens com o pedido

Comment: Sim, neste caso para que a modelagem fique correta é necessário criar uma tabela `Pedido_Item` ou algo similar com chave estrangeira para o `Pedido`.

Comment: Beleza vou tentar fazer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá então fiz porem não estou conseguindo obter o nome do produto e o valor segue o que realizei para analise onde estou errando?

```
insert into ITEMS(ID_PEDIDO, ID_PRODUTO, QUANTIDADE)values(3, 7, 1)

SELECT
    A.NOM_PRODUTO,
    A.VAL_PRODUTO,
    B.QUANTIDADE,
    B.ID_PEDIDO AS 'ITEM ID'
    FROM TB_PRODUTOS A RIGHT JOIN ITEMS B ON
        A.ID_PRODUTO = B.ID_PEDIDO WHERE B.ID_PEDIDO=3  --seleciona o pedido 3
```

Ao exibir os itens do pedido não estou conseguindo trazer o nome e valores como abaixo é exibido
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como trago os nome e valores será?

Resolvido assim:

```
SELECT<br>
    C.ID_PEDIDO AS 'PEDIDO',
    --A.ID_PRODUTO,
    A.NOM_PRODUTO AS'PRODUTO',
    A.VAL_PRODUTO AS 'VALOR UNITARIO',
    B.QUANTIDADE,
    (A.VAL_PRODUTO * B.QUANTIDADE)AS 'VALOR TOTAL POR ITEM'
    --B.ID_PRODUTO,

    FROM TB_PRODUTOS A INNER JOIN ITEMS B ON
        A.ID_PRODUTO = B.ID_PRODUTO
        INNER JOIN TB_PEDIDOS C ON C.ID_PEDIDO = B.ID_PEDIDO
        WHERE C.ID_PEDIDO=3
            GROUP BY C.ID_PEDIDO,
            A.NOM_PRODUTO,
            A.VAL_PRODUTO,
            B.VAL_TOTAL ,
            B.QUANTIDADE
```

Answer (score 1):

Você vai ter que mudar a estrutura dos seus dados. Porque agora você quer ter vários itens com o mesmo número de Pedidos.
Portanto imaginando que a sua tabela é de itens, você cria uma nova tabela que contenha as colunas:

- ID_PEDIDO
- ID_ITEM

Nessa nova tabela você terá o ID do Item e ID do Pedido (da sua tabela anterior).
Imaginando que você tenha uma tabela de itens no sistema também.
Aí você conseguirá fazer o relacionamento e os JOINS necessários nas suas queries.

```
Pedido 1 - Item 1 
Pedido 1 - Item 2 
Pedido 1 - Item 3 
Pedido 1 - Item 4 
Pedido 2 - Item 1 
Pedido 2 - Item 2
```

Comment: Acho que entendi vou fazer aqui e mando para ve se é o certo caso nao consiga